# Multicore processor core communication speeds

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I would look to find the speed of communication between the two cores of a computer.

I'm in the very early stages of planning to massively parallelise a sequential program and I need to think about network communication speeds vs. communication between cores on a single processor.

Ubuntu linux probably provides some way of seeing this sort of information?  I would have thought speed fluctuates.. I just need some average value.  I'm basically needing to write something up at the moment and it would be good to talk about these ratios.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I added bandwidth comparison as well to my answer, which may or may not be more relevant than latency depending on the exact nature of what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this benchmark: http://www.dragonsteelmods.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=6120&Itemid=38&limit=1&limitstart=4 (Last image on the page)

On an Intel Q6600, inter-core latency is 32 nanoseconds.  Network latency is measured in milliseconds which 1,000,000 milliseconds / nanosecond.  "Good" network latency is considered around or under 100ms, so given that, the difference is about the order of 1 million times faster for inter-core latency.

Besides latency though there's also Bandwidth to consider.  Again based on the linked bookmark, benchmark for that particular configuration, inter-core bandwidth is about 14GB/sec whereas according to this: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gigabit-ethernet-bandwidth,2321-3.html, real-world test of a Gigabit ethernet connection shows about 35.8MB/sec so the difference there is smaller, only on the order of around 500 times faster in terms of bandwidth as opposed to a 1,000,000 times in latency.  Depending on which is more important to your application that might change your numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The network speeds are measured in milliseconds for Ethernet ($5-$100/port), or microseconds for specialized MPI hardware like Dolphin on Myrintet (~ $1k/port).  Inter-core speeds are measured in nanoseconds, as the data is copied from one memory area to another, and then some signal is sent from one CPU to another (the data will be protected from simultaneous access by a mutex or a full-bodied queue).

So, using a back'o'the'napkin calculation the ratio is 1:10^6.

Answer (score 1):

Inter-core communication is going to be massively faster. Why ?

1. the network layer imposes a massive overhead in terms of packets, addressing, handling contention etc.
2. the *physical* distances will impose a sizeable impact

How you measure inter-core communication speed would be very difficult. But given the above I think it's a redundant calculation to make.

Comment: Agreed.  Inter-core communication is hugely faster.  I'm after a general ratio between network vs. inter-core communication.  I can understand that speeds are problem specific but we must have some idea of network speeds vs. inter-core processor speeds surely?

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-trivial thing to find. The speed of data transfer between two cores depends entirely on the application. It could depend on any (or all) of - the speed of register access, the clock speed of the cores, the system bus speed, the latency of your cache, the latency of your memory, etc., etc., etc. In short, run a benchmark or you'll be guessing in the dark.

Comment: Thanks Reinderien.  Out of interest, isn't there some 'theoretical maximum value'?  Specifically, would there be a maximum communication speed between two cores on a specific processor on a specific system?

Comment: @vivid-colours: theoretical maximum? Throughput or latency? If it's latency, the theoretical minimum latency is determined by the speed of light.

Comment: @ninjalj is right.  In fact I believe the speed of light is one of the limiting factors (last I read) of getting higher clock speeds in CPU, which is the reason for the recent trend of increasing number of cores rather than increasing clock speeds.

Comment: @Davy8 - A *really* interesting technology that has yet to see any exposure in the consumer market is asynchronous processor architecture. In such processors, there's less reliance on a global clock (or sometimes no clock at all), and subsections of a pipeline "finish when they finish".